# ASP.Net MVC Page gives 404 error for page route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am new to MVC and have to work on a project which is already done. and i am trying to add a sime test page but i keep getting `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found`

I have followed instruction from tutotial etc but i keep getting this error.

WHat i did

**Step 1**: on `HomeController` control i added new ActionMethod

```
public ActionResult Test2()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

    return View();
}
```

**Step 2:** On Right clicked on `Test2()` To add view `Test2.cshtml`

**Step 3:** Added simple HTML markup on this page `<h1> TEST2 PAGE</h1>`

Compiled the project & after running the project it opened following page in browser `http://localhost:54363/Home/Test2` with following error

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I even added following route to the RouteConfig.cs page

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "test2",
     url: "Test2",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Test2", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

    );
```

Also tried different route

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Test2",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Test2", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Nothing seems to work not sure why it is not opening the new page in it always give 404 error for all paths

`http://localhost:54363/Home/Test2`

`http://localhost:54363/Test2`

I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

ORDER OF Route

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "indexTest",
             url: "IndexTest/",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "IndexTest", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

            );
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "test2",
             url: "Test2",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Test2", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

            );


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

UPDATE:

When i create a new web application  project  i am able to create Test2 & run even without making changes to default RouteConfig.cs and page runs well. while in the project which is already done i am not able to add new page while following the same method

Comment: Show the order of how the route was added in the RouteConfig.cs. order is important to avoid route conflicts

Comment: Updated Question..

Answer (score 0):

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "test2",
            url: "Test2",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Test2" }
        );
```

And add [HttpGet] keyword to your Action

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Test2()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

    return View();
}
```

I think this will work for you.

Your Test2.cshtml view file must be under this path "View->Home->Test2" in your project.

Comment: This didn't work for us. I already had `[HttpGet]` on my controller action.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite often caused by the following missing from the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Check also if you `Global.asax` is not missing